# Lippmann-Schwinger equation for the Coulomb potential

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mp.mathematical-physics, sp.spectral-theory, quantum-mechanics, schrodinger-operators

Let $H=H_0+V$ be a Hamiltonian on $\mathbb{R}^3$ where $H_0=-\frac{\Delta}{2m}$ is the free Hamiltonian and $V$ is a potential.  Let us **assume first that $V$ decays sufficiently fast at infinity** and has only mild singularities (the former assumption excludes the Coulomb potential).

Under these assumptions one has Moller operators $\Omega_\pm$. Denote the corresponding IN/OUT states by
$$\psi_{\vec p}^\pm:= \Omega_\pm\left(\frac{e^{i\vec p\cdot\vec x}}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}\right).$$
They satisfy the stationary Schroedinger equation
$$H\psi_{\vec p}^\pm=E_{\vec p}\psi_{\vec p}^\pm\,\,\, (1)$$
where $E_{\vec p}=p^2/2m$.
These functions satisfy also a version of Lippmann-Schwinger integral equation
\begin{eqnarray}
\psi_{\vec p}^\pm(\vec x)=\frac{e^{i\vec p\cdot\vec x}}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}-
\frac{m}{2\pi}\int d^3y \frac{e^{ip|\vec x-\vec y|}}{|\vec x-\vec y|}V(\vec y)\psi_{\vec p}^\pm(\vec y).\,\,\, (2)
\end{eqnarray}

> **Now assume that $V$ is the Coulomb potential.** In that case the stationary Schroedinger equation (1) combined with an asymptotic condition at infinity can be solved (in term of special functions), so there are analogues of $\psi_{\vec p}^\pm$ in this case (and they are well studied). Is there a version  of Lippmann-Schwinger equation (2) for the Coulomb potential? Is it satisfied literally?

Comment: You should find this in "Quantum Scattering Theory for Several Particle Systems"
from L.D. Faddeev, S.P. Merkuriev